# Why does my render change the Colour of the strokes?

Tags: rendering, 2d

I'm new to Blender and use it for 2D animation and I can't figure out why it changes the colour of the strokes when I try to render it.

I want it to look like in solid mode, there everything's fine! When I try to render it it changes the blue and white strokes to red.

**Rendered:**
[image: Red]

**Preview (correct):**
[image: Blue]

Never had this problem before.